# Is there a way to make an ios app that is not available in the Appstore but I can send people privately

Tags: ios

I want to make a Christmas card with ARkit. I want to send this application to clients to wish them a merry Christmas and show them what I can do with AR. I was thinking about it, but it would be hard to get approved by Apple for the Appstore in a short amount of time.

Is there another way to send the application to my clients without being in the App store while using ARkit?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You can use TestFlight but for your situation I believe [Diwai](https://www.diawi.com/) is better, but you will still require their UUIDs :)

Comment: You can use TestFlight, but you still need to pay for that Apple Developer certificate which cost US$99/year to activate iTunes Connect.

Comment: Have a look at HockeyApp. It’s like TestFlight but doesn’t require Apple approval. You’ll have to get he device info from your friends for it though.

Comment: e.g. via _Enterprise Distribution_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enroll the [Apple Developer Enterprise Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/) which allows you to distribute app outside the store.

You can find all instruction [here](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/).

Comment: If you have a regular developer program membership, you can also follow the same [ad hoc distribution](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html) steps.

Comment: Sure, but the ad hoc distribution requires the devices registration and has a limit to 100. Considering @Nami92 use case would not be really handy to ask every client his own iPhone UDID (which is not really user friendly to get) just to send them Christmas cards. I think enterprise program is a much more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to share your app

1. Using **Test Flight** account : 
   Here you need there Apple ID so that you can invite all of them directly from iTunes test flight.
2. Using **Diawi.com** :
   This is simplest way of sharing your app with your client. Remember you need your client's iPhone UDID to be registered in devices on apple account before sharing diawi link.
   (Note: Drawback of Diawi is its link gets expired after some time)